# why hmac-csrf-token store the csrf token in cookie?

Tags: security, web, csrf

In [OWASP CSRF](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#hmac-csrf-token), it introudce HMAC CSRF TOKEN. I'm confused why hmac-csrf-token store the csrf token in cookie?

```js
response.setCookie("csrf_token=" + csrfToken + "; Secure)
```

1. If csrf token will not be added at request header, then the prevention is not working. Because the attackers can still use user's cookie.
2. If csrf token will be added at request header, then Why is it necessary to put it in cookie? The csrf token in this document contains both the content before encryption and the content after encryption. The validity of the csrf token can be verified if only put in the header.

```js
message = sessionID + "!" + randomValue
hmac = hmac("SHA256", secret, message)
csrfToken = hmac + "." + message
```

I don't know why csrf token can be put in cookie. Is there any scenario in which the CSRF token is placed in the cookie?